# Generate nested hashes from strings and deep merging in ruby

Tags: ruby, hash, merge

I have a hash in the database in JSON format. eg

```
{
  "one" => {
    "two" => {
      "three" => {}
    }
  } 
}
```

I need to generate this from a string. The above example would be generated from the string "one.two.three".

Firstly how would I do this?

Second part of the problem. I will be receiving multiple strings - each one building on the last. So if I get "one.two.three", then "one.two.four", I hash to be this:

```
{
  "one" => {
    "two" => {
      "three" => {},
      "four" => {}
    }
  } 
}
```

And if I get "one.two.three" twice, I want the latest "three" value to override what was there. Strings can also be of any length (e.g. "one.two.three.four.five" or just "one"). Hopefully that makes sense?

Comment: Just split and make recursive hashes. There are multiple deep-merge examples on the web, including a gem or two; I'd probably just search for those first--I don't recall their names at the moment.

Comment: I'll try some of those deep-merge Hash methods. Though do you know off the top of your hread how do go from "one.two.three" to hash["one"]["two"]["three"]? I know you can go "one.two.three".split(".") to get the array.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To generate nested hash:

```
hash = {}

"one.two.three".split('.').reduce(hash) { |h,m| h[m] = {} }

puts hash #=> {"one"=>{"two"=>{"three"=>{}}}}
```

If you don't have rails installed then install activesupport gem:

```
gem install activesupport
```

Then include it into your file:

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/hash/deep_merge'

hash = {
  "one" => {
    "two" => {
      "three" => {}
    }
  } 
}.deep_merge(another_hash)
```

The access to the internals would be:

```
hash['one']['two']['three'] #=> {}
```

Comment: I didn't know about deep_merge - thanks. Can you give me a good way of turning "one.two.three" to hash["one"]["two"]["three"]?

Comment: If you use `h[m] ||= {}` in your reduce block, you can get rid of the deep merge altogether as it will merge it automatically when feeding the existing hash into the `reduce` again. This however only works if you have only hashes (and not e.g. Arrays).

Comment: OK cool, so what would be the easiest way to merge a whole bunch of hashes with each other? (i.e. not just a.deep_merge(b), but [a,b,c,d].deep_merge)

Comment: I don't understand your question, maybe you want create new one?