# Generate nested hash from string

Tags: ruby, ruby-hash

I want to generate nested hash from string.
Input:
key: a.b.c
value: true
Output:
{:a=>{:b=>{:c=>true}}}

I have the following method from the stackoverflow: [Generate nested hashes from strings and deep merging in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11944330/generate-nested-hashes-from-strings-and-deep-merging-in-ruby)

```
hash = {}

"one.two.three".split('.').reduce(hash) { |h,m| h[m] = {} }

puts hash #=> {"one"=>{"two"=>{"three"=>{}}}}
```

This generates an empty value for the last object and I need to assign a value to it through method itself without specifying keys name.

Any idea on how to achieve this?

Comment: This question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095077/ruby-convert-array-to-nested-hash)